# CS0246-The type or namespace name 'TableName' could not be found

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

When I added entity framework to my project and connected with a table
it does not create Classes for the Tables and show me this error

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TableName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried searching about it and nothing helps.

Comment: Do you already have classes with the same names?

Comment: Have you considered including the relevant code in your question so that we can provide you some advice?

Comment: Are you trying db first  flow for creating your models ?